# Normalizer of a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $ H\leq G $ and $g\in G$. Prove that $N(g^{-1} Hg)=g^{-1}N(H)g$. Here $N(g^{-1}Hg)$ is the normalizer of $g^{-1}Hg$.

Can somebody please help me with this problem?

Comment: What's the definition of the normalizer?

Comment: Normalizer of an element $a \in G$ is defined as $N(a)=\{x \in G : xax^{-1}=a \}$.Normalizer of a subset $S$ of $G$ is defined as $N(S)=\{x \in G : xSx^{-1}=S\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a follow-your-nose proof. You know that $N(H)=\{x\in G:xHx^{-1}=H\}$.

So if $n\in N(g^{-1}Hg)$ then we know that $ng^{-1}Hgn^{-1}=g^{-1}Hg$. This implies that $gng^{-1}Hgn^{-1}g^{-1}=H$. Thus $gng^{-1}\in N(H)$ and $n\in g^{-1}N(H)g$. That is one inclusion. The other inclusion is arrived at by reversing each of the steps.